# Как разбить список на подсписки элементов Python

Tags: python, list

Есть список с фразами, его нужно преобразовать во множество списков, в котором каждая фраза - один список и слова в котором - его элементы.

**Пример:**

Исходный список:

```
['Cat dog', 'green fox', 'deep sea']
```

Полученные списки:

```
['cat', 'dog']
['green', 'fox']
['deep', 'sea']
```

Comment: `set(el.split(' ') for el in lst)`

Comment: `[x.split() for x in lst]`

Comment: @CrazyElf до тех пор пока тут дают ответы на элементарные вопросы, элементарные вопросы никуда не денутся

Answer (score 0):

Изучи библиотеку [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

```
    import numpy as np
    firstList = np.array(['Cat dog', 'green fox', 'deep sea'])
    secondList = np.reshape(firstList, (len(firstList),-1))
    print(secondList)
```